# Can not take a selector(Xpath) of "Account settings button" and "find my iPhone" in iCloud

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, automation

I need to click "Account settings" and "find my iPhone" buttons on iCloud.com (not at the same time). But none of my selectors working.
Looks like there are no frame on-page, but Xpaths not matching.

Steps:

1. Sign in to iCloud account
2. Find elements "Account setting" and "Find my" buttons

This is what I'm using now:
For Find button:

```
WebElement settings=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
elementToBeClickable
(By.xpath("//div[@class='user-name-with-chevron']")));
settings.click();
```

For Account settings:

```
 WebElement settings = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
 elementToBeClickable(By.xpath
 ("//div[@class='cw-button symbol-button link-button']")));
 settings.click();
```

I appreciate any help.
sorry if my questions stupid, just start to learn.

[html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjroZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have missed to switch back to default content after log in.
I tried below code and it worked for me :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); //switch to default content 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.cw-button.symbol-button.link-button")).click(); //click on Account settings
```

After switching from iframe to default content i was able to locate any webelement on page.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, yes it is working now))

Comment: Hi, can you upvote the answer so that others could also benefit from it if they face the similar problem.